# Адаптивный сайт

Tags: bootstrap

Проблема работаю через bootstrap 4, разделил все по колоннам, но на моб. устройствах они залезают друг на друга,вроде бы ширину не подключал нигде, спасибо.

```
<div class="div_checked_baggage col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
          <span class="checked_baggage col-xl-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">Checked Baggage</span>
          <span class="checked_baggage_size col-xl-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">23kg</span>
          <span class="checked_baggage_price col-xl-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">80$</span>
          <a href="#" class="x_link"><span class="x_span"></span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="checked_baggage_num col-xl-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
          <span class="checked_baggage_title col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">Checked Baggage</span>
          <span class="checked_baggage_size_2 col-xl-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">23kg</span>
        </div>
        <div class="baggage_numeral col-xl-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1">
          <input type="number" name="baggage_num" placeholder="0" class="baggage_numeral_class">
        </div>
        <div class="price_div col-xl-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
          <a href="#" class="button_price"><span class="price_button_baggage">80$</span></a>
        </div>
        <div class="sports_equipment_info col-xl-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
          <div class="sports_equipment">
            <span class="sports_equipment_title">Sports Equipment</span>
            <img src="images/question.png" class="img_question" alt="question" title="You Can Bring Ski, Snowboard, Surf equipment, Bicycle, etc.">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="price_div_2 col-xl-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
          <a href="#" class="button_price"><span class="price_button_baggage">30$</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс `col-[1-12]` расчитан на мобильные девайсы. Вот его и используй в своих колонках
Вот гайд https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/